# Derivation of $(iw)^{n}$ into the format $A+ib$

Tags: complex-numbers, fractional-calculus

How to derive $(iw)^{n}$ into the format $A+ib$ ($A$ is the real part, $B$ is the imaginary part),
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, $w<0$, $n$ is a fractional number such as $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, ...$?

Note that $\sqrt{xy}$ sometimes not equal to $\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Do you know about Euler's formula for complex numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially looking at
$$
(iw)^n = |w|^n(-i)^n
$$
we know that
$$
-i = \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = \mathrm{e}^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}
$$
so we find
$$
|w|^n\mathrm{e}^{n\cdot i\frac{3\pi}{2}}
$$
or
$$
|w|^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}n\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}n\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Is your first equation correct, shouldn't it be $|w|^n(-i)^n$

Comment: Yes you are correct.